# No module named googleapiclient when trying to import Google Sheets Data

Tags: python, api

When I try to setup the google sheets api, I'm trying to run the quickstart.api, and I'm getting this error

```
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

I tried reinstalling the google client and had two failures that I can't solve

```
Failed building wheel for google-api-python-client
```

and

```
Failed building wheel for httplib2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the python3.6-dev package, which is installed using apt:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
```

After this, repeat your installation using pip as before.